# How to display a dialog from a non-activity class in Android?

Tags: android

Well, I dont need it to be a dialog, actually. It might be some alternative... I just want to notify the user that its "Loading..."

I have a class that extends AsyncTask, inside of another taks.

onPreExecute I want to display "Loading..." and
onPostExecute I want to dismiss it.

The only way I could think of doing that is via a dialog.

Problem is, dialog needs a context passed to its constructor, and this class is just a data transmitter so its not an activity.

What do I do?

Comment: there is no another way. You need a context

Comment: take asynctask as inner class in your activity..

Comment: I cant, the structure is too complicated.

Comment: I think we will need some more information to answer your question.  From what you have given us, it seems that you strictly want to display a `Dialog` without any `Context`, however as @blackbelt already said, this is not possible unless you implement your own `Dialog` class.  If we know precisely what you are trying to do, then we can recommend better alternatives.  For example, it may be possible to have the `Activity` that starts the `AsyncTask` also display the `Dialog`, however that might not be applicable in your case.  Can you provide more details please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `AsyncTask` inside the `Activity`, thus you can easily obtain the `Context`.

OR

If you don't want to put it inside the `Activity`, you can create a constructor which accepts `Context` as a parameter, then store it as a class variable. Then, when you call the `AsyncTask`, pass the caller's `Context` as the argument.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context mContext;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    // the rest of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fro this you have two solutions 
1.take the asynctask as a inner class in activity ..

OR

2.create class as below and use the context anywhere in your project..

```
public class ApplicationContext extends Application {

/** Instance of the current application. */
private static ApplicationContext instance;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public ApplicationContext() {
    instance = this;
}

/**
 * Gets the application context.
 * 
 * @return the application context
 */
public static Context getContext() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ApplicationContext();
    }
    return instance;
}
}
```

mention it in the manifest as `android:name="com.afbb.activitys.ApplicationContext"`

and get the context as `ApplicationContext.getContext()` use it to show dialog..

Comment: Solution 1 worked... :) A bit overkill, because now I have to put this huge piece of code in a few more activities, but at this time it is working and with time, when I learn java and android better I will find another solution.

Comment: ok..but second solutions also has to  work..i am checked and here it is coming..may be something went wrong..ok..anyway you got it..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the System Window

1、Get the WindowManager with getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

2、Inflate your dialog view

3、Create a WindowManager.LayoutParams. be careful of the Flag.

4、add the View with WindowManager.addView(view, layoutparams);

5、When dismiss the dialog, WindowManager.removeView(view);

[WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html)

Comment: OMG, Every View obtains a Context.